# How to enter div element value in database

Tags: php, html

I am created one IMS System in that in that i have to store div element value in database so if anybody know solution than please help.Below is my code

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <p class="words"><b>Total Net Amount(In Words):-</b></p>
    <div id="container" class="conversion">
    </div>
```

Comment: Where does the value come from?

Comment: words is only for styling i have given

Comment: Unless you are using AJAX or something else to call a PHP function, you are going to need [A Form](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp) instead of a div, then the submission of your form would [connect to the database] (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp).  I can assure you that there are a lot of similar questions right here on SE and examples found by using your favorite search engine.